# How can I use geemap instead of folium in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium, geemap

In the following codes:

```
import sys
import io
import folium
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import geemap

class my_app(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(my_app, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('GRSGA')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        cordinate = (32.3265, 52.65241)
        map = folium.Map(title='geors', zoom_start=8, location=cordinate)
        data = io.BytesIO()
        map.save(data, close_file=False)
        web_view = QWebEngineView()
        web_view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        layout.addWidget(web_view)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QWidget{
        font-size: 35px
        }
    ''')
    myapp = my_app()
    myapp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('closing window')
```

i can display folium map in pyqt. but i want to use geemap instead of folium like the following code:

```
cordinate = (32.3265, 52.65241)
    map = geemap.Map(title='geors', zoom_start=8, location=cordinate)
    data = io.BytesIO()
    map.save(data, close_file=False)
    web_view = QWebEngineView()
    web_view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
    layout.addWidget(web_view)
```

this codes return the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\earth engine\gee_app\train1.py", line 28, in <module>
    myapp = my_app()
  File "D:\earth engine\gee_app\train1.py", line 17, in __init__
    map.save(data, close_file=False)
  File "D:\earth engine\gee_app\venv\lib\site-packages\ipyleaflet\leaflet.py", line 2220, in save
    embed_minimal_html(outfile, views=[self], **kwargs)
  File "D:\earth engine\gee_app\venv\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\embed.py", line 302, in embed_minimal_html
    snippet = embed_snippet(views, **kwargs)
TypeError: embed_snippet() got an unexpected keyword argument 'close_file'
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so then don't forget to mark it as correct, if you don't know how to do it then check the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` method of `geemap.Map()` does not accept the `close_file`, also the fp must allow to write string instead of bytes, therefore `io.StringIO()` must be used.

```py
class my_app(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(my_app, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("GRSGA")
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        web_view = QWebEngineView()
        layout.addWidget(web_view)

        cordinate = (32.3265, 52.65241)
        map = geemap.Map(title="geors", zoom_start=8, location=cordinate)

        data = io.StringIO()
        map.save(data)
        web_view.setHtml(data.getvalue())
```

[image]